# How to display all data in array?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to display data from an array in firestore. I displayed it, but only [0] in the array is showing. I'm trying to get all the data in the array to show.

```
builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
          itemBuilder: ((_, index) {
            List<Widget> tiles = [];
            
            for (Map post in snapshot.data![index]['posts']) {
              tiles.add(
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(border:  Border.all(color:Colors.black)),
                    child: Center(
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(post['postText'], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                        subtitle: Text(post['fromUser'], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              );
            }
            return Expanded(
              child: ListView(
             
               children: tiles,
              ),
            );
          }),  
        );
        }
        else{
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
        }
      },
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJdoJ.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you include what is before the posts in json response?

Answer (score 0):

Edit

To answer your qn about newest to oldest:

I suggest you put a `FieldValue.timestamp` field in your group chat documents! Then, you can order them like this:

```
  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getDoc(groupID) async {
    var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection('groups')
    .where('groupChatId', isEqualTo: groupID)
    .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)  // <- Here!
    .get();
    return qn.docs;
  }
```

(All of that I copied by hand, since you hadn't provided this code as text, as I asked you to!... )

If you don't have a timestamp field, there is a way to still find out when a document was created... but I don't know how. Plus, in this case, I guess you want the time a certain FIELD was created in the document...! I don't know if that's possible. In fact, for that you'll probably have to do:

```
    List<Map> posts = snapshot.data![index]['posts'];

    // Sort list according to the 'date' field in each Map in the list:
    posts.sort((mapA, mapB){
      return mapA['date'].compareTo(mapB['date']);
    });  

   // Then you'll use posts in your for-loop instead of snapshot.data![index]['posts']:
    
    for (Map post in posts) {
      tiles.add( /*etc*/);
    }
```

Btw, if you want it to update when new messages come in, you can do like this:

```
import 'dart:async';

// Put the below in the State of a StatefullWidget:

  StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>? qn;
  List<DocumentSnapshot>? eventDocs;

  void getDocStream(groupID) async {
    var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    qn = firestore.collection('groups')
        .where('groupChatId', isEqualTo: groupID)
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .snapshots().listen((event) {
      // Put here everything you want to happen when new things happen in the stream!
      // For example:
      setState(() {
        eventDocs = event.docs;
      });
      // Now, you can use eventDocs instead of getDoc(groupID), as you did before.
      // Just remember that it will be null at first!
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (qn != null) qn!.cancel();  // This is to prevent the stream from going on, after you've left the page or even closed the app...
    super.dispose();
  }
```

---

Old answer:

But you're *telling* it to display only post [0]!...

If there are more posts in each document, and you want to display all of them, you need to make a for-loop or something. For example:

```
    itemBuilder: ((_, index) {
      List<Widget> tiles = [];

      for (Map post in snapshot.data![index]['posts']) {
        tiles.add(
            ListTile(
              title: Text(post['postText']),
              subtitle: Text(post['fromUser']),
            ));
      }

      return Expanded(
        child: Column(
          children: tiles,
        ),
      );
    }),
```

And btw... Next time you ask a qn, plz paste your code as text rather than an image! So that we can copy-paste it into our answer, rather than having to retype it from the image. It's so easy to make a mistake and then you get an error coz we didn't copy it right.

Comment: it worked, but how can i make it to where it refreshes when a new post comes through

Comment: When using the `.get()` operator as you do, you will get the data only once, at the time of running the command. If instead you want it to listen to new messages and update automatically, you need a `snapshots().listen()`. If you would provide your code as text, rather than an image, I could show you how! But a tip would be: Use a `StreamBuilder()` instead of a `FutureBuilder()`. Then I think the `.listen()` part is implicit...

Comment: I edited it so you can copy the code

Comment: I also got a new error where it says 'Every child of a RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox must have an ID in its parent data.'

Comment: You got that error after changing to a StreamBuilder()? Could you plz include the new code, as well? (Unless that IS the new code, that you have posted above)

Comment: and I'm trying to get it to where I have to use shrinkWrap without getting an error

Comment: I haven't changed it to stream builder. I still get the error

Comment: Read your code again: You're not supposed to return a `ListView()` from the itemBuilder of the `ListView.builder`!... You're only supposed to return a `tiles[index]` or something like that. A single Widget. Then the builder builds as many as it needs, when it needs them. Could you plz post the image of the original code again, so that I can see how I was thinking!  Coz what I wrote can't be returned from a ListView.builder either...

Comment: I added the picture back

Comment: Nice! Also see my Edit in answer.

Comment: where am I supposed to put the new solution? Do I replace the whole ListView.builder?

Comment: That's not the picture I meant... I meant the one featuring an itemBuilder! (But the Firebase code is good to have too! Would you mind providing that bit as a text? )

Comment: Just exchange exactly the piece of code that I wrote for that other piece of code that I wrote! I.e. just the "return" bit from the itemBuilder... Hey, I said "Change this for this", how hard can it be? 

Comment: I'm going to sleep.  See you tomorrow!

Comment: thanks for all your help. I fixed it. Just need to get it to where it updates with new docs

Comment: and how can I get it to descend from newest to oldest?

Comment: See new edits.  I removed the part about returning just a list tile instead of a ListView(), which clearly wasn't right... (That would kind of take us back to the beginning! ) And I've given some tips for the rest of your issues!

Comment: PS You can upvote, if you want!  (No pressure)

Comment: how would I add FieldValue.timestamp? Ive never used it

Comment: Google it! Or post a new qn, if you really can't find it. (It's starting to feel like I'm writing your entire program...)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
title: Text(snapshot.data![index]['posts']['postText']),
```

Comment: Hey Rasyid thanks for your contribution. I tried your solution, but it gave me an error. _TypeError(type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')

Comment: This answer is completely wrong, and does not in any way address the problem. It doesn't even run. Unfortunately, I upvoted it, before I saw that it was wrong, and now I can't undo that action... It would be helpful if others could down-vote it though! Or indeed, if @Rasyid could just delete it...